# Gaussian distribution into equiprobable parts

Tags: matlab, gaussian

Im trying to divide a Gaussian distribution into equiprobable parts. Im using the following code:

```
function main
mu=100;
sigma=2;
n=100;
k=3;
samp = mu + sigma.*randi([20,100],1,n);
%hist(samp)
v=optim_m2(samp,k)
end

function v=optim_m(d,k)
v=-inf;
mu=mean(d);
sigma=var(d);
for i=1:k

[x, ~] = fminbnd(@(x)     (0.5*(  1+erf( (x-mu)/(((sigma^2)  )^0.5 )   )   )  -i/k   )^2    ,mu-3*sigma,mu+3*sigma);

v=[v,x];
end
end
```

I get some pretty strange results such as negative values and so on. If I use the same function but with small natural numbers everything seems to work fine. 
PS. Im a NOOB so ...:) dont judge too harsh

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What is the intended output?

Comment: I have to determine the boundaries as on the picture http://s9.postimg.org/p6wh7dbzj/untitled.jpg

Comment: How are the boundaries defined? 1/8 probability/likelihood for each segment? What is the input a samle set or a distribution?

Comment: Yes, surfaces are symmetrical in size. The input is a distribution.

Comment: This is a math question, not a programming task. Knowing the cdf, you have to solve `normcdf(x,mu,signa)=y` to x. Then set x to your intended propability boundaries [0,1/8,2/8....] and get the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Matlab commands, you can simply use:

```
boundaries = norminv(1/8:1/8:7/8,mu,sigma);
```